# Select is not updating the user info in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We have a user edit profile form where change existing info of that user and click update. The problem is that simple inputs are updating the user information but selects don't. Here is the code:

**TS**

```
 private populateForm() {
    const unusedFields = [
      '_id',
      '__v',
      'username',
      'email',
    ];

    const userInfo = Object.assign({}, this.user);
    unusedFields.forEach((field) => delete userInfo[field]);
    this.SettingsForm.setValue(userInfo);
  }

  private buildSettingsForm() {
    this.SettingsForm = this.fb.group({
      country: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      gender: [null, [Validators.required]],
      jobTitle: [null, [Validators.required]],
      lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      description:[null, [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.SettingsForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
  }

  UpdateUser() {
    this.usersService.EditUser(this.SettingsForm.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form action="" [formGroup]="SettingsForm" (ngSubmit)="UpdateUser()">
...
...
  <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-signup">
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="lastName" type="text" id="lastName"
                    formControlName="lastName" />
                <span *ngIf="!SettingsForm.get('lastName').valid && SettingsForm.get('lastName').touched"
                    class="help-block">Please enter a valid username!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group form-signup col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg">
                <option value="">{{user.country}}</option>
                <option ngDefaultControl [ngValue]="country.name" *ngFor="let country of countries"
                    formControlName="country">{{country.name}}</option> 
            </select>
            <span *ngIf="!SettingsForm.get('country').valid && SettingsForm.get('country').touched"
                class="help-block">Please enter a country!</span>
        </div>

...
...
</form>
```

As you see the second one is select of countries and whatever you change it doesn't update the value after refreshing the page it gets the same value as it was before. This issue is happening only with selects. So the issue is in Angular side not in the back-end because other inputs are updating the value. What is wrong and How can we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Set `formControlName="country"` to the `select` tag and not to `option`..
Change the code like this,

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="country">
  <option value="">{{user.country}}</option>
  <option ngDefaultControl [ngValue]="country.name" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.name}}</option> 
</select>
```